# Data Import Wizard Issue

Tags: data, data-import-wizard

We found that the user is not able to see Accounts, contacts and person accounts in new Data Import wizard. However, he told he was able to see before when there was a standard wizard.

His profile is having Create,Read and Edit permission to accounts, contacts and also permission set of creating person account. What i found is, his profile has different page layouts with different recordtypes of account(There are total 4 recordtypes), but in recordtype settings only Person account is enabled for the profile. Is it the reason, because every recordtype is not enabled and causing the issue because recordtype respects page layout assignment as well?

Salesforce team also responds the same and when we assigned every recordtypes, it worked and the objects were visible. So, please confirm if this is the issue with recordtypes only?

Answer (score 0):

This would be caused by the user not having access to the record types for the objects as Salesforce support confirmed to you.

As long as the user has create and update record on the relevant objects then they should be able to use the data import wizard, and they will need the permissions on the specific fields to import.

If the user only has read permission on an object, e.g. Account then again they would not be able to import using the Wizard.

The main area where there can be difficulty is on Custom objects where a user needs the [Import Custom Object](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_import_general_permissions.htm&language=en_US) permission to import them through the [Wizard](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=import_with_data_import_wizard.htm&language=en_US).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, they do not need permission for custom objects which is fine. Also, I believe the Create and Edit permission should also be there if recordtype is assigned otherwise i believe the issue will still persisit because if recordtype is assigned but object say Account has Read Permission, then it will create problem. Is that true?

Comment: Ok, if you are happy with the answer then you can accept it.

Comment: Yes, it is helpful. Just wanted to confirm one thing , say all recordtypes are assigned but then the permission was changed to Read instead of Read,create and Edit for the object,say account, then i believe the account again will not be visible in import wizard? Because Recordtype settings is not only for Read, also for Create and Edit. I also tested the same in sandbox and seems the theory is true. Can you confirm on it?

Comment: Yes that is correct if they only have read on Account then it would be hidden in the import wizard. I have edited my answer to clarify this point.